# Whats the difference between these two statements?

Tags: sql-server

I am student of SQL and am running these two queries on the Northwind database. Both the below queries are fetching different datasets. I think both of them are the same but what I cannot grasp is how are the fetching different data sets.

```
select o.*
from dbo.Orders o
where 36 < (
    select Quantity
    from [Order Details] od
    where ProductID = 17
    and od.OrderID = o.OrderID
)
```

This retrieves 9 records.

```
select o.*
from Orders o
join [Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
where Quantity < 36
and ProductID = 17
```

This retrieves 27 records.

Can someone please explain to me this conundrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.

The first one tests whether

`36 < Quantity`.

The second tests whether

`Quantity < 36`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if we could see the data you're using.

But it seems to me that the first query (unless I've misread it, since it's structured rather unconventionally) selects rows where `36 < Quantity` and the second selects rows where `Quantity < 36`.

`36 < Quantity` is the same as writing `Quantity >= 36` ...so hopefully you can see that these conditions are opposites. I would guess your two result sets contain completely different rows to each other, not just a different number of rows